# How to get Excel 2013 to show username of person that has file open?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

When trying to open an Excel 2013 file on a shared network drive that someone already has open, a prompt appears that says the file is open by "another user."  In Excel 2010, Excel was able to display the actual name of the user as long as the user name was entered in Options>General>Personalize your copy of Microsoft Office. But, now with Excel 2013, even though our user names have been entered in that field, Excel 2013 does not display our names when an attempt is made to open a file that is already open.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Details pane showing in Windows Explorer?  If so disable it (Organize>Layout>Details pane) and try opening the file again.